# R: argument to 'which' is not logical

Tags: r

I run these codes:

```
library("ggplot2")
library(dplyr)

head(iris)

remove <- which(subset(iris, Sepal.Width>4.0 | Sepal.Width <2.25 
                   | is.na(iris$Sepal.Width)))
```

Then a bug comes out:

> Error in which(subset(iris, Sepal.Width > 4 | Sepal.Width < 2.25 |
>   is.na(iris$Sepal.Width))) : 
>         argument to 'which' is not logical

Why? THX!

Comment: Just a guess: Usage of `which` is not clear to me and this works `remove <- subset(iris, Sepal.Width>4.0 | Sepal.Width <2.25 | is.na(iris$Sepal.Width))`, what do you want to do?

Comment: That's exactly what I want!